# How to display text in a WPF GridView that contains carriage returns

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, multiline

I have a grid view that has two simple columns, a report number and a short description. It is common for this short description to have some carriage returns. If that is the case, I would like the row to expand its height to fit all of the text in.

Currently the field renders with possibly the first line displaying, but then cutting off text below it. How could I display all the text, with it adjusting the height as needed?

And can this be done on a per-row basis, as in, if the next report did not have a description with carriage returns, it would just show on one line?

It would be rather [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192469/how-can-i-display-text-with-carriage-returns-in-a-gridview-in-asp-net), but in WPF versus ASP.net

This also may due to using a theme application wide. If that is the case, how can I enforce it only in this grid view?

XAML:

Originally I had it only as

```
<GridViewColumn Width="365" Header="Desc" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding desc}" />
```

I have also tried

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="colDesc" Header="Desc" Width="75" >
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

We are using an application wide theme, that very well may be setting the high explicitly. If so, I am leaning mostly towards the fact (From the comments) that the theme is overriding a default value for how this works. If so, how do I have it act the way the it is supposed to (again, from the comments, it sounds like this is the default behavior).

Using the second example, here is what it looks like:

[image]

In here it looks like the text is larger, so again, I would want the cell to adjust to the hight needed. And some of these have multiple lines, so as you can see I would not see the remaining content. I have also tried to set the Height on the text block, but that had no effect.

Comment: Just tried this.  DataGridTextColumn auto-sizes vertically to fit.

Comment: Are you using a TextBox with Wrapping enabled?

Comment: @Phil interesting. On a per cell/row basis?

Comment: @Blam I originally wasn't, but then added one after doing some my searching, and it made it worse.

Comment: Worse how?   And do you have height to Auto?  I would test with binding a single row/column with a line feed to a text control.   You may need to go to RichTextBox.

Comment: I had an existing datagrid with <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />.  I added an Environment.Newline in the text, and it wrapped no problem.

Comment: @Blam worse in the way that even the first line, or single line fields were placed lower to be illegible. As for auto, not sure (not by code right now), I think the height may be set. Will update

Comment: Sorry for the delay, some XAML has been posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked.

```
 public string TextBlockText { get { return "one line \r\ntwo line"; } }

 <TextBlock Height="Auto" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=TextBlockText}" />
```

I will leave it to you on how to put a TextBlock in a ListView.

Comment: The question is directly related to how this should be incorporated into a gridview. I already have this in code, but to accept this as an answer I can't just place it into a TextBlock

Comment: I do not have access to the code right now, hence why none yet. Effort? I am sorry if my comment came across as rude or harsh, I was simply stating that a text block can go anywhere, when I'm actually concerned about it in a grid. It's not a programming class, was simply asking a question since this obviously wasn't working for me.

Comment: Your question was "list view" and now "grid".  If it is not working then post the code that is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I may have used the terms to interchangeably. Trying to access code right now.

Comment: Just finished adding the XAML. It was very simple, but from reading the comments, this is how it is supposed to work by default.

Comment: Did you try Height = Auto.  Try a single TextBlock to a single row.  You can use a binding of Items[x].Desc.  If a lone TextBlock is bad then disable the theme application wide and see if that fixes it.  I don't know how to disable a theme on a single control.

Comment: I did Height = Auto in the text block, but then noticed in the theme that Height for the ListViewItem was also enforced, and removed that (unfortunately, I didn't see that when posting the XAML). It now works exactly as described.